# Check if a list is not empty pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to return for specific ids in mongo a list named list_followers that i ve inside the database. However, some  documents of the database have zero list's size. Thus, I got key_error for list_followers.

```
list_of_ids = []
for cursor in collection.find({ "list_followers" : { "$exists":True}}):
    id = cursor['_id']['uid']
    list_of_ids.append(id)
    followers = cursor['list_followers']
    print len(followers)

print len(list_of_ids)
```

How can I query only the cursor with list_followers bigger than zero? I ve tried `{"list_followers":{"$gt":0}}` or `{"list_followers":{"$gt":{"$size":0}}}`  but thats not what I want.

Comment: show us whats inside your db, please

Comment: Approximately {id:..., ..., name:"", list_followers:[array of ids]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
collection.find({'list_followers': {'$not': {'$size': 0}}}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator. You should also use `$exists` in your query, because without it, it will match even documents that don't have the field `list_followers`:

```
collection.find({'list_followers': {'$not' : {'$size' :  0}, '$exists' : True}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) for not being equal to 0:

> The $size operator matches any array with the number of elements
>   specified by the argument.

```
collection.find({"list_followers": {"$not": {'$size': 0}, "$exists": True}})
```

Thanks to @Christian P for the note about `exists` requirement here.

---

Alternatively, you can check for the `existence` of a first element:

```
collection.find({"list_followers.0": {"$exists": True}})
```

Comment: this is exactly my answer

Comment: @alexvassel give it a minute.

Comment: @alexvassel not sure, I'm improving the answer by proving more information and options. You were first to suggest the `$size` option, I admit.